# Extracting Matching Rows | WHILE Condition

Tags: while-loop

Im trying to fetch all rows from table posts that have the same $cid and $tid , at the moment the results2 query only shows one row that has these values within one echoed table , I would like to have my while statement find multiple rows and for each row create new a table . Any help would be very much welcome.

```
// table topic also contains same value as $cid and $tid
    $result= $con->query("SELECT * FROM topic WHERE cat_id='".$cid."' AND id='".$tid."' LIMIT 1");

    if($result->num_rows ==1 ) {

// start of table to echo out
            echo "<table width='100%'>";    

        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

// I would like this query to return all rows that have same values $cid $tid
    $result2= $con->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE  cat_id='".$cid."' AND topic_id='".$tid."' LIMIT 1");


            //condition to check if row meets result2
            while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){

    //generate a table a populate it with the results if more than one row is found with same result create another table 


         // echo table rows and populate it with results
                echo "<tr><td valign='top' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'><div style='min-height: 125px;'>".$row['topic_title']."<br />by ".$row2['post_content']." - ".$row2['p_date']."<hr /><br />".$row2['post_creater']."</div></td><td width='200' valign='top' align='center' style='border: 1px solid #000000;'>User Info Here</td>

    </tr><tr><td colspan='2'><hr /></td></tr>";

    }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$result2= $con->query("SELECT * FROM posts WHERE  cat_id='".$cid."' AND topic_id='".$tid."' **LIMIT 1**");
```

Remove LIMIT 1 and or set it to a bigger number